# Looking for a free or commercial Image Processing C# library

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm working on a project which compares image files. Before I start I decided to ask for external sources, like a commercial **SDK** or something open source.

I tried to write a sample where it compares 2 image files too measure how similar they are, and output a percentage result. But no luck, long time to execute and weak precision. So if someone had experience in that direction that will help me.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to measure similarity; what kind of similarity are you looking for?  Are you looking to locate an image within another image (i.e. pattern matching) or are you looking at two images of the same size and comparing directly?  Are you mostly interested in identifying consistency of shapes, textures, lighting, colors?  The type of comparison you wish to do will help to suggest the kind of API you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

Answer (score 2):

AForge.NET is excellent...
[AForge.NET](http://aforgenet.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The frameworks below is the best for image processing in C#

[AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)

[Accord.NET](http://accord-framework.net/)

[Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure about requirement , what kind of similarity you want. If you can put more details, i can help you out.

Comment: Well i need to find out an integer which represents the Percentage of Similarity between 2 Images ,currently I`m Comparing Each Pixel RGB with Each Homologue in other Side (like same Point of 2 Pictures) ,i Reduced that by Searching only 40 % of Pixels which are Selected Randomly using Math.Random(x,y) .